Center a span element around highlighted text and break-word overflow on both sides
I have a span element that can have a long text which is truncated using css at the end if it overflows. The text also contains some highlighted text, but if this part is towards the end of the long text, the highlighted part is not visible. I need the highlighted part to be around the center of the text that is visible, and overflow should work on both sides. How can I achieve this?


<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .dont-break-out {
      overflow-wrap: break-word;
      word-wrap: break-word;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="max-width: 200px;">
    <span class="dont-break-out">
                <span style="max-width: 100%;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;display: -webkit-box;-webkit-line-clamp: 1;-webkit-box-orient: vertical;">
                    This is a very long text and at the end of this very long text, I have a <em style="font-size: larger;">highlighted</em> part that should be visible.
                </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>




unfortunately with css you will not be able to have both beginning ellipsis (direction: rtl) and end ellipsis working together
An idea can be to used js to display string from the beginning of the highlighted part

if the string start by the highlighted part there is no ellipsis at beginning
if there is one we can imagine add the characters ... at beginning of
string



[...document.querySelectorAll('.dont-break-out')].forEach(one => {
  [...one.querySelectorAll('span')].forEach(span => {
    const initText = span.innerHTML;
    span.innerHTML = initText.substring(initText.indexOf("<em"));
    if (initText.startsWith('<em')) {
      return;
    }
    span.innerHTML = '...' + span.innerHTML;
  })
});
.dont-break-out {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
<div style="max-width: 200px;">
  <span class="dont-break-out">
                <span style="max-width: 100%;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;display: -webkit-box;-webkit-line-clamp: 1;-webkit-box-orient: vertical;">
                    This is a very long text and at the end of this very long text, I have a <em style="font-size: larger;">highlighted</em> part that should be visible.
                </span>
  </span>
</div>



